# CORS not working across virtual machine

Tags: javascript, iis, virtual-machine, cors, parallels

I am trying to access a rest service on the guest system (windows) from the host machine (osx) in Parallels 9.

I have CORS set to allow everybody to use the service. Server and the client on different port
When the javascript is accessing the service i am still getting the error message that because of CORS, it is not allowed.

> Failed to load resource: Origin `http://127.0.0.1:9000` is not allowed
>   by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

It is working when the javascript and the server are on the same machine.
So I assume there is an issue with the virtual machine's network. Any idea why CORS not working over the virtual machine?
thank you

Comment: Hmm, back then i didnt find anything. And I was not using outside of the VM. But last time I was trying to access it, and eventually it was working. Not sure what was the issue before. 
What I was ensuring is to have the proper addresses (outside ones) in the CORS setting... hope it helps